# How to set a UniqueConstraint in a ManyToMany relationship in Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model (`MyModel`) which can have multiple `User` as owners (ManyToMany relationship). Each `User` can own multiple `MyModel` instances.

The idea is that a user can create a `MyModel` instance through an API. But I want to set a constraint that the `MyModel` instance that the users create has to have a unique name within the `MyModel`s that the user owns. It can be non-unique across the database though.

I am trying to do so by explicitly defining a `MyModelOwner` as the `through` model in a ManyToMany field but I am confused on how should I handle the `UniqueConstraint`?

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        unique=True,
    )
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        related_name='+',
        through='MyModelOwner'
    )


class MyModelOwner(models.Model):
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['owner', 'my_model'],
                name='unique_my_model_owner'),
        ]
```

Comment: This looks reasonable. What problem does it have?

Comment: Plus, the through model was not even needed, the automatically generated through model would have handled uniqueness anyways.

Comment: What happens is if I create a `MyModel` using Django Admin it validates for a unique name because the create method there doesn't assign an owner. However if I create via the API (which is just a call to the `MyModel.objects.create` with an owner assignment then it doesn't validate the uniqueness and I'm able to create multiple instances with same name

Comment: Multiple instances with the same `name`? When you have `unique=True` in `MyModel`? This shouldn't be possible, it's enforced at the database level (among others). Are you sure you have `unique=True` in `name` when you make these tests?

Comment: I realized after your comment that my answer was not actually possible, so I deleted it.  You will have to write a trigger to enforce this constraint.

Comment: What about moving the `name` field to `MyModelOwner`?